# Getting excluded variables between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, union

I have two sql server 2005 tables like so:

```
Table A
varName  varStatus
AGE      Text
AGENDA   Text
TEACH    Text


Table B
varName   varDesc
ACT       Text
AGE       Text
SAT       Text
GPA       Text
```

I need one or two queries to get all the varNames between the two tables that are not in both tables. For instance, above example would use:

```
Table A:  AGENDA, TEACH
Table B: ACT, SAT, GPA
```

This is correct since AGE is the only varname that appears in both tables.

Comment: not to self: use except!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(SELECT varName FROM tableA EXCEPT SELECT varName FROM tableB)
UNION
(SELECT varName FROM tableB EXCEPT SELECT varName FROM tableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all records that in A, but not in B

```
SELECT A.* FROM 
A LEFT JOIN B ON A.varName = B.varName
WHERE B.varName IS NULL
```

Similarly, this query will give you records in B, but not in A

```
SELECT B.* FROM 
A RIGHT JOIN B ON A.varName = B.varName
WHERE A.varName IS NULL
```

And finally, all you need to do is just to UNION both queries together

```
SELECT A.* FROM 
A LEFT JOIN B ON A.varName = B.varName
WHERE B.varName IS NULL
UNION
SELECT B.* FROM 
A RIGHT JOIN B ON A.varName = B.varName
WHERE A.varName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variables can be in the single list, use a UNION with NOT IN

```
SELECT 'A' AS sourceTable, varName
FROM   tableA
WHERE  varName NOT IN (SELECT varName FROM tableB)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS sourceTable, varName
FROM   tableB
WHERE  varName NOT IN (SELECT varName FROM tableA)
```